# Data structure to use: need to access both by priority and name

Tags: java, priority-queue

What data structure to use when I need to

- access an object by priority - to dequeue
- access an object by name/id to update the priority

With Java's PriorityQueue, I can't access a node directly by its name/id property can I?

---

I was thinking along the lines of use a priority queue, plus a TreeMap so I can search by name in log(n) time, then modify the priority. But I doubt the Queue will know of that? In that case, I need to remove and re-add the node? Is that worth the overhead? What complexity is it to remove/re-add a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In that case, I need to remove and re-add the node?

Yes.

> Is that worth the overhead?

That depends on your requirements. Only you know that.

> What complexity is it to remove/re-add a node?

Insert and remove from a PriorityQueue is O(log n).

Comment: So in your opinion, that's the most approperiate data structure to use for this use case? Or is there something better?

Comment: If you need to be able to change the priority based on a sorted key, it is the best combination I can think of. If you can use a HashMap instead of a TreeMap it will be slightly faster as its O(1), but the PriorityQueue will still be O(log n).

Comment: I suppose the decision to choose Tree or Hash Map will be the chance of collision for the data set? How do I know if the chance of collision of the data set is small or large?

Comment: I would assume its small unless you have a poor hashCode. If the hashCode is always `1`, don't use HashMap. ;)

Comment: I will be using whatever java does in this case. But I suppose u mean if my name can have many duplicates then its a bad idea? If so I think hash set is the way to go as names should be unique in this case

Comment: A Map cannot have duplicate keys so you have a problem no matter what map you use.  The problem is if many keys have the same hashCode. I would use a *map* not a set.